# get materials informations with python

Tags: materials

## my code.

```
for o in bpy.data.objects:

    material = bpy.context.scene.objects[o.name].active_material
    color_RGB = material.diffuse_color
```

## but the console return AtributeError

> > > AtributeError: 'NoneType' objects has no atribute 'diffuse_color'

pls, how can i get this information of the active material.
Here is my complete code, my problem is in the line 19: https://hastebin.com/odubesasuc

Comment: I'm using blender render.

Comment: And im using blender v2.79

Comment: the variable material return : bpy_struct, Material("Material.004"). Can i get this material name??

Comment: Try simplifying it. Why do you use bpy.context? Just use `o.active_material.diffuse_color`. I tried it just now, and [this](https://i.imgur.com/xXRtzHe.png) is what I got. (D is a shortcut to bpy.data, and it's only available in Blender's scripting console; elsewhere you need to type in bpy.data, or define the shortcut yourself).

Comment: out of the loop, the expression works normally, but when I try inside of the loop it does not work.

Comment: I'm not a scripting guru, so I can't help you here. But I suggest you [edit] your question and include a little more of the script. And editing will bump the question to the front page, so possibly someone who knows Python better than I do will see it.

Comment: If an empty material slot is selected the active material is `None`, hence the none type error.  Test for this.  Also suggest `for o in scene.objects: material = o.active_material`.

Comment: your loop is including all objects cameras and lights will not have materials assigned and will cause errors. include a check for o.type == 'MESH'

Comment: Thank you guys!! I had no idea. Thank you for your help.